# Android how to start activities/access class between two libraries

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application using one main application x, two library projects like y and z.

I can able to access library like calling x to y, x to z and y to z also using adding library as a project. In this sutation i can't able to call z to y.

Thanks

Comment: You libraries include a lot of packages?

Comment: Yes, i have difference UI in libraries y and z.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify UI in y and z libraries - copy all libraries packages to your project and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a wrong architecture you have there. You can't have two libraries both depending on each either. If you really need to have a library, just converge y and z into a single project and have that used as a library by x.